# boost::asio and use of send()

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio

When using a `boost::asio::ip::tcp:socket` there are many methods one can use to write/send data. There's also asio::write that takes the socket as a parameter, etc. My question is is there any compatibility issues (gotchas) with the boost asio libraries when using the standard `send()` function?

Should one categorically never use the standard `send()` function on a `boost::asio::ip::tcp:socket`? Or maybe it works fine, but why use `send()` when you already have everything you could possibly need in this regard within the boost::asio libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the boost asio send and send_to function for UDP sockets while the write method is used for synchronous stream write i.e used for TCP and cannot be used for UDP as it is "stream write".